# What phrase "follow along" stands for?

Tags: phrase-meaning

I am passing a course where the teacher was saying that: "So just follow along and we'll have plenty of time to go over all this things". What does "follow along" mean in this context? Does it mean "follow this course" or something else?

I could not find this phrase using like "follow along". This is always "follow along with something". Maybe you can propose some examples where you can use just "follow along".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It probably means "follow the teacher's instruction" or perhaps "follow the discussion in the text".

Quite likely the true intention is to say "Don't ask that question now and perhaps I will address the topic later."

---

By the way, the phrase  "where the teacher saing that..." is not grammatically correct.

"where the teacher said that..." or "where the teacher was saying that..." express what I think the meaning was here.

Comment: You are right, thanks for grammatic correction :)

Comment: Hmm, about true intention, that's it, I think! Because he always repeat "just don't worry, we will talk about this later". Thank you!

Comment: Just follow the teacher's instruction (and don't ask a question right now, don't worry right now, the teacher explain it later) - this is right meaning, yes. I've understood it after some thinking. It's a pity I can't mark your answer as usefull (not enough reputation)